# Was Jango Fett a Sharpshooter?

Tags: star-wars, attack-of-the-clones

We all know that prior to the beginning of the Clone Wars, Jango Fett killed Zam Wissell with a Kamino saberdart using a Velocity-7 dart shooter while being located from a considerable distance. Is that ability enough to catalogue him as a sharpshooter? Or it was just a lucky shoot.

[image: Still image from Star Wars Episode 2 Attack of the Clones (2002)]

Comment: a dart is generally sharp so...yes? (in seriousness - is 'sharpshooter' a term in the SW universe?)

Comment: @NKCampbell - Jango Fett doesn't show up here (But Zam Wissel).
https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Category:Sharpshooters_and_snipers

Comment: dubious canon source considering it lists Ben (Luke's son) Skywalker

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [*Official Star Wars Fact File (#22)*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/The_Official_Star_Wars_Fact_File_22) describes Fett's execution of Wessell as being typified by "*deadly precision*". If that's not a synonym for '*sharpshooter*', I don't know what is.

> Zam's second attempt to kill Senator Amidala was
> similarly thwarted when Padme's Jedi bodyguard and his
> Padawan rescued her from an assassin droid and its cargo
> of deodly kouhuns. Jango watched os the Jedi pursued Zam
> through the streets of Coruscant. **It was only when they
> apprehended the wounded Zam and asked her who she
> was working for that Jango felt compelled to terminate her
> life. Jango fired a Kaminoan sabredart with deadly
> precision, and Zam was silenced forever.**

Comment: @Valorum- I accept the meaningful point in your answer. Thanks!